# Flashing Page For Split Second Before Fade In

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code, it flashed the site for about a split second before it loads the page how do I stop it from doing this so it just fade in the Divs smoothly when the new page is loaded?

```
$('#home').animate({'opacity' : 0}, 0);
fadeInDivs(['#home']);
function fadeInDivs(els) {
e = els.pop();
$(e).delay(750).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000, function(){
   if (els.length) fadeInDivs(els);
});
```

};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, you need to set #home to be invisible in CSS. However, if you want your page to be visible when JS is disabled, you could do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(
        "<style type='text/css'>" +
        "#home { opacity: 0; }" +
        "</style>"
    );
</script>
```

... so the css will only be added when JS is enabled. This may be overkill these days.

Comment: Nice tip about JS being disabled. +1

Comment: Thanks! I'll just go and place it in the css

Comment: @n3dst4 I placed display: none in my css and it doesnt become visible when the page is reloaded.  is there a part i missed?

Comment: I just realised you're animating the opacity, so you'll need to put `opacity: 0;` in your css, not `display: none;`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have #home set to display: none; in the stylesheet? The flash is probably occurring because content shows before the animate function kicks in. Adding display: none; would prevent the content from showing, then allow the animate function to reveal it.